# grub rescue error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I get the following error:

[image]

My system specs are:

- HP 245 G6 Notebook PC
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 + Kali Linux

The error happened after I tried to edit the partitions for Kali Linux.
Both partitions have an *ext2* file system.

Comment: Typical of trying to boot wrong version of grub. Or you have multiple grub installs. Also occurs if you install grub in both UEFI & BIOS boot mode, and then try to boot from UEFI boot menu with wrong version, UEFI or BIOS. Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair but was system booting Ubuntu ok? Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789